# Seeking Direction to Address Draftiness in a 1964 2-Pane Sliding Patio Door: Repair, Replace, or Insulate?

Tags: repair, door-frame, winterizing, sliding-glass-door

I am looking for a direction on the best course of action to pursue for my 2-pane sliding patio door that feels drafty during winter weather. The door is likely original to the house built in 1964 in Michigan.

**Other Concerns**

- I've noted significant caulking separation and cracks in the caulk, resulting in wide openings between the door frame and the brick wall all around the door frame
- Structural integrity may be compromised due to the flimsy door frame - in some places I can bend the door frame by hand, pulling it away from the glass.  In particular, see the image where I can slide a piece of paper between the door frame and the glass. The seal gasket appears to have slipped away from the glass.

Here are some options that involve directly repairing or replacing the door:

- **Repair**: Repair existing doors - Some repairs to consider: Replacing glazing beads/gaskets/weather-stripping/sealant, replace glass, repair or reinforce the frame fitting
- **Replace**: This is beyond any reasonable repair or repair is not cost-effective:  replace the doors with a new modern energy-efficient door.

I also have options that leave the door as-is:

- **Cover**: I can use a thermal curtain special covering to insulate the door from inside for the winter
- **Postpone**: despite the issues, it is still good enough, no repair or replacement recommended or necessary

**Question**

What would be the most sensible approach to address energy efficiency, i.e. eliminate the draftiness and temperature conduction issues of the door for the winter and the summer months going forward?

[image: whole door]
[image: top right]
[image: middle right]
[image: bottom right]
[image: bottom from the outside]
[image: paper between glass and frame]
[image: side picture showing sliding doors of the patio door and the storm door]

Comment: How is the condition of the fuzzy weatherstripping?

Comment: I don't see any fuzzy weatherstripping on the doors. I'm not sure if there was any put in in the first place

Comment: Those are your options. Which you choose is up to you. Not sure how this didn't get closed as opinion based right away...

Answer (score 1):

Patio doors are usually something of a design disaster in this regard.

Right now. I'd suggest covering the entire opening with a shrink film kit.

Long term, if this is a home you own rather than rent. I'd seriously consider replacing the whole thing with real door and windows. Double doors with a removable astragal can give you a similar opening width and seal much better.

Comment: Thanks. Are you talking about double French doors, or just any doors that swing out? For astragal, I have a hard time imagining what the removable astragal functions like and what do you do with the space it occupied once you remove it. Won't it leave a gap or an opening? When you are saying it is a design disaster do you mean that it is difficult to design patio doors that prevent drafts, am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: I've done some research I see that astragal is a configuration thing. Doors that swing open are also more expensive compared to a sliding door.  Astragal can be removable or can also be part of one of the doors (see Renewal by Andersen doors that swing open one of them has astragal as part of the door itself).  Budget-wise I rather spend less money, thus sliding doors is more likely for me than a door that swings open.  Replacing the opening with just window is a consideration but I think a door makes more sense. My question is narrowing down to keep existing sliding doors+insulate, or replace